# CountIF over a criteria range

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following columns of data:

`Pool Amount|Calculated Payment| 10% | 15% | 20% | 30% | 40% | 50%`

Pool Amount and Calculated Payment are static currency fields, the percentage fields all contain variations on this formula:

e.g. C2 `=IF(B2<(A2*0.9),A2*0.9,IF(B2>(A2*1.1),A2*1.1,B2))`

The formula caps the calculated payment at the thresholds determined by the relevant % in relation to the Pool Amount. What I want to do is a count for each % field showing the number at the minimum and maximum.

For one cell in the 10% field I would use:

Min `=COUNTIF(C2,A2*0.9)` and Max `=COUNTIF(C2,A2*1.1)`

I could then produce two columns of 0s and 1s and `SUM` them but it seems a bit clunky. Is there a variation on the following formula that I could use:

`=COUNTIF(C2:C1162, A2:A1162*0.9)` to show a total count in one cell?

Is this potentially a job for a pivot table with a custom function?

Comment: Sounds like you need to start getting into [array formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNTIF can't be used to compare each element of one range/array against each element of another but you can use SUMPRODUCT to do that and avoid formulas that require "array entry", i.e. this formula to count the Mins in the 10% field

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B1162< A2:A1162*0.9)+0)`

and for Maxs

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B1162> A2:A1162*1.1)+0)`

Those formulas just use the condition from your original formula applied to ranges rather than single cells. SUM can be used in place of SUMPRODUCT but then you do need **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**

Comment: +0 gives you 1s and zeroes rather than TRUE/FALSE so that SUMPRODUCT or SUM can process them, you can use this which is perhaps more understandable `=SUM(IF(B2:B1162> A2:A1162*1.1,1,0))` but again that would require "array entry"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish what you want with an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx). Your formula for the "minimum 10% cell" should be correct, just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you enter the formula to make it an array formula.

I believe you need to use `SUM` instead of `COUNTIF` in the array formula (to sum all TRUEs as 1 and FALSEs as 0). It has been a while since I've used one.

Comment: Thanks will look into array formulas have never used them before.